# IntelliJ IDEA reporting unresolved variable TypeScript errors, but won't allow ':any'

Tags: intellij-idea, typescript, webstorm

I have the following bit of TypeScript code in an Angular 2 application.

```
   constructor(private windows:WindowService, private http:Http) {
        http.get('config.json')
            .map(res => res.json())
            .subscribe(config => {
                this.oAuthCallbackUrl = config.callbackUrl; // here
                this.oAuthTokenUrl = config.implicitGrantUrl; // here
                this.oAuthTokenUrl = this.oAuthTokenUrl
                    .replace('__callbackUrl__', config.callbackUrl) // here
                    .replace('__clientId__', config.clientId) // here
                    .replace('__scopes__', config.scopes); // here
                this.oAuthUserUrl = config.userInfoUrl; // here
                this.oAuthUserNameField = config.userInfoNameField; // here
            })
    }
```

Every place where I have a `// here` I get an error from the IDE saying that I have an 'unresolved variable', such as `unresolved variable callbackUrl`.

The issue is that this config object is the result of a JSON file being fetched by the app, and I have no idea how I would define its type ahead of time.

I thought I might be able to change the subscribe line to show `.subscribe(config:any => {` or something, but that has not worked.

The code compiles fine.  Everything works in the browser (and through Webpack) without issue. I just would like to get rid of the error in the IDE without having to add 7 `//noinspection TypeScriptUnresolvedVariable` comments to surpress them.

Comment: making config of type any should fix it, is the noImplicitAny property set to false in tsconfig.json?

Comment: @toskv Except that it causes the IDE to complain prolifically.  It appears to be invalid syntax (at least doing it the way I mention it in the post).

Comment: If you want to add explicit type information to `config`, you have to wrap it in parentheses: `.subscribe((config: any) => ...`. Though if you are using specific properties from the returned object, one would assume that you can indeed write a type definition with those properties instead of just `any`.

Comment: @DCoder That was all that I needed: ( )  Thanks!

Answer (score 5, accepted):

As @DCoder mentioned in a comment above, the solution was to wrap the `config` parameter in parenthesis and then add the type to it.

```
constructor(private windows:WindowService, private http:Http) {
    http.get('config.json')
        .map(res => res.json())
        .subscribe((config:any) => {  //               <-- WORKS NOW!
            this.oAuthCallbackUrl = config.callbackUrl;
            this.oAuthTokenUrl = config.implicitGrantUrl; 
            this.oAuthTokenUrl = this.oAuthTokenUrl
                .replace('__callbackUrl__', config.callbackUrl) 
                .replace('__clientId__', config.clientId) 
                .replace('__scopes__', config.scopes); 
            this.oAuthUserUrl = config.userInfoUrl;
            this.oAuthUserNameField = config.userInfoNameField; 
        })
}
```

It was the lack of parenthesis that was keeping me from being able to add typing information of any kind on `config`.